# How to set content size of UIScrollView dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I got question about `UIScrollview`.

The story is I have a `UIView` named ChartsView which I re-draw it myself by override method `drawRect()`. The content of drawing was generated dynamically. So I do not know its size until runtime. The question is how/where can I set its super view's (scrollView) content size dynamically?Any idea about that?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

// not this way. it's fixed size.....
        ChartsView *chartsView = [[ChartsView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 800)]; 

        self.scrollView.contentSize = chartsView.frame.size;

        [self.scrollView addSubview:chartsView];

    }
```

Answer (score 62):

One more easy way

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    float sizeOfContent = 0;
    UIView *lLast = [scrollView.subviews lastObject];
    NSInteger wd = lLast.frame.origin.y;
    NSInteger ht = lLast.frame.size.height;

    sizeOfContent = wd+ht;

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
}
```

Comment: nice trick. It can be used for any `UIScrollView`. +1 for that.

Comment: I'd just like to add one thing. Some of you may like to put this code in viwDidAppear: because your UIView may be drawn before viewDidAppear but after viewDidLoad is called; This will enable you to have access to the view's latest height.

Comment: lastObject returns the last object indexed in subviews array, not the most bottom subview on the screen. in fact, lastObject has nothing to do with the view's position and using it is wrong.

Comment: problem occurred when back to pop navigationcontroller

Comment: For some reason this was never returning the right subview for me, even though it was correct in my nib file. I ended up just ditching the call for the last subview and hardcoding what subview I wanted it to be based off of.

Comment: Why would the lastObject be the right height? Wouldn't it best to add the height of all the objects?

Answer (score 25):

It is not 100% guaranteed that the last object in scrollView.subviews array will return the highest y-origin object in your scroll view.  The subviews array is arranged by Z-Index (i.e the last object in the subviews array will be the object stacked the highest and will be the top-most subview in the scroll view's subviews.  Instead it is more accurate to use a basic sort function to iterate through the subviews and get the object with the highest y-origin.

**Swift 4**

```swift
extension UIScrollView {
    func updateContentView() {
        contentSize.height = subviews.sorted(by: { $0.frame.maxY < $1.frame.maxY }).last?.frame.maxY ?? contentSize.height
    }
}
```

Usage (in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or whenever your content size updates):

```swift
myScrollView.updateContentView()
```

Comment: Remember to add this line before calling the updateContentView(): 

self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: This is really the only legitimate solution I've found. The oft-repeated one (below) where you constrain the content height to that of the scrollview's superview does not work. I did modify this and turn it into an extension of UIView, so I could query the scrollContent view that people tend to nest under the UIScrollViewController,  and find out the height necessary to contain its subviews at any given time.

Answer (score 7):

**swift** (2.0)

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnLatestButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let height = btnLatestButton.frame.size.height
    let pos = btnLatestButton.frame.origin.y
    let sizeOfContent = height + pos + 10
    scrollview.contentSize.height = sizeOfContent

}
```

Above ofcourse is when you just have a fixed amount of views on your scrollview.
IOS Rocks method is available but was not good for me, created more space then I needed.

```
    let lastView : UIView! = scrollview.subviews.last
    let height = lastView.frame.size.height
    let pos = lastView.frame.origin.y
    let sizeOfContent = height + pos + 10
    scrollview.contentSize.height = sizeOfContent
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to IOS Rocks and CularBytes for the leads on this.  I found two problems (for me) with the above solutions:

1. I always have a container UIView as the only child of my UIScrollView, so I had to update the way I look up the last view in that child UIView (see below)
2. I am offset'ing my content in the UIScrollView and as such needed to calculate the absolute position of that last UIView (so, relative to the window not the parent view)

Also I am using autolayout to pin the sides of the UIScrollView, so I don't need to worry about width (as is CularBytes).

Here's what I came up with and works (in Swift 3.0):

```
func setScrollViewContentSize() {

    var height: CGFloat
    let lastView = self.myScrollView.subviews[0].subviews.last!
    print(lastView.debugDescription) // should be what you expect

    let lastViewYPos = lastView.convert(lastView.frame.origin, to: nil).y  // this is absolute positioning, not relative
    let lastViewHeight = lastView.frame.size.height

    // sanity check on these
    print(lastViewYPos)
    print(lastViewHeight)

    height = lastViewYPos + lastViewHeight

    print("setting scroll height: \(height)")

    myScrollView.contentSize.height = height
}
```

I call this in my `viewDidAppear()` method.

Answer (score 4):

Calculate UIScrollview contentSize dynamically(depending subviews frame)

Swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var contentRect = CGRect.zero

        for view in self.scrollView.subviews {
           contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
    }
}
```

Objective C:

```
 - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                        CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;

                        for(UIView *view in scrollView.subviews)
                           contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect,view.frame);

                           scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
                       });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var height: CGFloat
    let lastView = self.scrollView.subviews[0].subviews.last!

    let lastViewYPos = lastView.convert(lastView.frame.origin, to: nil).y  
    let lastViewHeight = lastView.frame.size.height

    height = lastViewYPos + lastViewHeight
    scrollView.contentSize.height = height
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your answer, explaining why your code snippet solves the OP's problem. More info here: [answer]

Comment: While it could have been better with more details, the answer is fine and helpful as it is.

Comment: Thank you, I will be adding more details from now on

Answer (score 3):

While using scrollviews in storyboard it’s better to calculate content size according to number of views present in scrollview rather than giving content size programmatically with static value.
Here are the steps to get content size dynamically.

**Step 1 :**
Add Scrollview to view in storyboard and add leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints (All values are zero).

**Step 2 :**
Don’t add directly views which you need on directly scrollview, First add one view to scrollview (that will be our content view for all UI elements). Add below constraints to this view.
Leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints (All values are zero).
Add equal height, equal width to Main view (i.e. which contains scrollview). For equal height set priority to low. (This is the important step for setting content size).
Height of this content view will be according to the number of views added to the view. let say if you added last view is one label and his Y position is 420 and height is 20 then your content view will be 440.

**Step 3 :** Add constraints to all of views which you added within content view as per your requirement.

[image]

[image]

Ref:https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/uiscrollview-dynamic-content-size-through-storyboard-in-ios-fb873e9278e

Comment: This is the best answer I found after searching a lot.

Comment: I do not find that this works. Your method here tells iOS that the scroll content is as high as the screen, but this may not be true. If you then reduce the height of your scrollview at runtime (to make room for a new UI element that’s introduced below it), you end up with empty space at the bottom of the scrolling content.
And what if your scrolling content is taller than the screen? Telling iOS that the scroll content is only as high as the screen will cut it off at the bottom.
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 5**

You can also programmatically update contentView of the `UIScrollView` by adjusting `UIScrollView.contentLayoutGuide` , here is the example of constraining contentview to the height of `yourView`:

```
self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
self.scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
self.scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

    // not this way. it's fixed size.....
            ChartsView *chartsView = [[ChartsView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 800)]; 

            self.scrollView.contentSize = chartsView.frame.size;
            [self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:chartsView];

    }
```

Comment: still no luck.  I try to find a workaround , set content size of scrollview in Charts view when drawing done.Now the question is what kind of api i can use for getting actuall size of chartsView
((UIScrollView *)[self superview]).contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

// not this way. it's fixed size.....
        ChartsView *chartsView = [[ChartsView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 800)]; 

        //self.scrollView.contentSize = chartsView.frame.size;
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(chartsView.frame.size.width, chartsView.frame.size.height)];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:chartsView];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension written on Swift 3

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func updateContentViewSize() {
        var newHeight: CGFloat = 0
        for view in subviews {
            let ref = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.height
            if ref > newHeight {
                newHeight = ref
            }
        }
        let oldSize = contentSize
        let newSize = CGSize(width: oldSize.width, height: newHeight + 100)
        contentSize = newSize
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use contentInset with

> storyboard

and

> programmatically

follow [image: this works best]