# UIScrollView Resizable?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` and I take a  `UIImageView` and an `UITextView` that scrolls vertically. 
The scrollview is 320*700. I want to do the scroll size depend upon the `UITextView` size, The image is same size but the text changes depend on the content.

How can I setup the scrollview's size to change only when I've got more or less text in the UITextView?

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your `UIScrollView's` size dynamically according to the size of your `UITextView`using something like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    float sizeOfContent = 0;
    UIView *lLast = [scrollView.subviews lastObject];
    NSInteger wd = lLast.frame.origin.y;
    NSInteger ht = lLast.frame.size.height;

    sizeOfContent = wd+ht;

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
}
```

Please also refer to [How to set content size of UIScrollView dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518790/how-to-set-content-size-of-uiscrollview-dynamically) to be able to understand better .

Comment: that was my last try before posting my answer...didn't work though. Am I doing something wrong? If I setup the scrollview.contentsize like that it doesn't even move.

Comment: @devC That's why you are supposed to add some code to your question.

Comment: Sulthan the scrollview right now it looks like this://scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);

Comment: Do i need to make another view in the scrollview? Right now I have my main view, inside that is the scrollview and inside the scrollview I've got the image and textview that's pretty much it.

Comment: simply increase the content size of the scrollview when u increase the size of the textview as simple as that ... @devC