# how to set the scroll view contentsize dynamically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had an application in which i am setting the content size of the scroll view dynamically according to the number of buttons which i am creating from an array.like this `

```
for(int i =0;i<[sarray count];i++) 

    {

        NSMutableDictionary *dicttable=[sarray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *head=[dicttable objectForKey:@"cat"];
        btn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        int j=i+1;
        btn.frame = CGRectMake((j-1)*87,0,87, 44);
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_hvr.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];

        btn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       [btn setTitle:head forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tag = i;
        [btn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

            [Scroller addSubview:btn];
                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        if(btn.tag==0)
          {
            sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

           }
       else
          {
               btn.selected=NO;



          }


    }

    }


        [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake([sarray count]*85, 44)];
```

`
but here the problem is after the last button also the scroll view scrolls .it need not to be happend,i need the scrolling ends with last button on the view,can anybody help me on this

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518790/how-to-set-content-size-of-uiscrollview-dynamically

Comment: chnge the following and check. CGRectMake((j-1)*87,0,85, 44);  [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake([sarray count]*87, 44)];

Comment: @Gup thats working already,but my problem is if it reaches first button then need to stop scrolling to right and if it reaches last button then i need to stop scrolling to left.thats the real pbm.in my case it is scrolling a little bit more than that in both cases

Comment: set scrollview bounces to NO scrollView.bounces = NO;

Comment: @Gup  fine thanks buddy..but the smoothness is gone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set scrollview bounces to NO

```
scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

yes as you said it looses the smoothness. But no other choice. If you found any sol please update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

hey i am sending you complete example to make button dynamicay and seting the content size scrollview on number of count ,i had just given u one example code u have to set the size of frame of button as u requried

```
    UIScrollView *scroll_View=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:scroll_View];


int y=0;

for(int i =1;i<10;i++)

{

   // NSMutableDictionary *dicttable=[sarray objectAtIndex:i];

   // NSString *head=[dicttable objectForKey:@"cat"];
   UIButton* btn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    btn.frame = CGRectMake(y,89,100, 50);
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_hvr.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    btn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [btn setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.tag = i;
    [btn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    [scroll_View addSubview:btn];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    y=110*i;

}




   [scroll_View setContentSize:CGSizeMake(y, 400)];
```

enjoy coding

Answer (score -1):

You just declare one yMargin variable of type `CGFloat` and initialize it with some required value as 0. Now every time whenever you are adding a new subview vertically do `y+=lbl.frame.size.height;`

Now `setContentSize:CGSizeMake([sarray count]*85, y margin+someRequiredMargin)];`

(someRequiredMargin - you want to add below )