# Not able to resize UIView with dynamic content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am working on ios project. I have one View with nib file. In that I have added one more view called RootView. 
That RootView has Label, Description followed that two buttons. I have set the constraints in StortyBoard: rootView->Label (vertical Space =50px) , Lable->Description (50px)

Now when I am increasing size of either label or description, root view size is being increased. But inside code, If I do self.rootView.frame.size.height it is still giving old root view height.

Can someone point me, how to get new rootView height inside the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Here is the answer:

[self.rootView LayoutIfNeeded], Have to call this before getting new updated value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of increasing root view width or height, take a base view something like `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` and add your objects (label, button etc.) into it, set content size for ***base view*** according to your dynamic text for `UILabel` and `UITextView` (assuming for description).

Here's the help.

[Dynamically getting height of UILabel according to Text return different Value for iOS 7.0 and iOS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068849/dynamically-getting-height-of-uilabel-according-to-text-return-different-value-f)

[How to set content size of UIScrollView dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518790/how-to-set-content-size-of-uiscrollview-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks for Quick reply, but I have slight different problem. I am not able to get latest updated height inside the code. I have modified my question with more detail. Can you please look into that once again.