# how to dynamically increase the height of scroll view?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

i placed a table view and a view in a scroll view how to change the scroll  view's height dynamically depending on the number of cells in the table view and the content present in content view also

Comment: It's better not do like this. A table view with header and footer view cannot fit your demands?

Comment: actually in my view also i need to place a table view so it's not possible to place as you said @YunCHEN

Comment: use constraints to handle the above scenario, the scroll view bottom should be attached to table view's bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set contensize of your ScrollView.
You can do it by proper autolayout or programatically as

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```

In **Swift 3**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
var contentRect = CGRect.zero
     for view: UIView in scrollView.subviews {
        contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)  
     }
contentRect.size.height = contentRect.size.height + 20
scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
}
```

In **Swift 4**

Here is a more concise version in Swift 4. Credit for Swift 4 to this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518790/how-to-set-content-size-of-uiscrollview-dynamically)

```
 extension UIScrollView {
    func updateContentView() {
         contentSize.height = subviews.sorted(by: { $0.frame.maxY < $1.frame.maxY }).last?.frame.maxY ?? contentSize.height
     }
 }
```

You can accomplish the same in storyboard. 
There is hack to accomplish that.

1. Add Constraints to scrollview top, left , right and height as 1000 or more as per requirement. Your Scroll View may exceed your view controller height itself.
2. Then you can add Constrain between your Scroll View Bottom & Last Subview (in your case View containing TableView and PaymentView ) Bottom as 0 or with 10.

3.You can now delete your height constraint.

But before this make sure consraints between all subviews of scrollview is proper.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148127/discussion-on-answer-by-luckyshubhra-how-to-dynamically-increase-the-height-of-s).

Answer (score 1):

You only have to do 2 things to achieve this

1. satisfy all constraints of scrollview when adding view and tableview in it by adding constraints to all sides of scroll view so that scrollview can figure out its content size, but make sure give fixed height to tableview( we will later increase its height when loading remote data)
2. Now when you get data from remote url then after calling tableview reloadData you have to implement this method in your code

```html
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    for constraint in tableView.constraints{
        
        if constraint.firstAttribute == .height{
            
            constraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
            break
            
        }
        
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    
}
```

Then your tableview height will increase according to its content height and your scrollview content size will also increase then only your outer scrollview will scroll instead of tableview scrolling

Comment: now check swift code in edited answer and let me know if you face any problem

Comment: try to call this method in your method from which you are fetching remote data, when table finishes reloading its content, you can use dispatch_after or performSelectorAfterDelay to perform this method after tableview reload