# how to increase the height of scroll viewheight dynamically in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiscrollview

How can i set the constraints that here two table views are using so that both are dynamical and i need to change the height of scroll view so that both table views and it needs to fit the whole screen and my layout will be as shown below in the image

[image]

Comment: You can set content size of scroll view dynamically. I hope its well answered in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839101/how-to-dynamically-increase-the-height-of-scroll-view) well.

Comment: i tried ur code but it is not changing as expected @luckyShubhra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you are using `tableview` in `scrollview` ? It is not good approach to use `scrollable entity` into `scrollview`!  You can take one `tableview` and can create multiple cell for every type of your content like `payment view`, `cart view` etc. You can use multiple section also as per requirement. For example, your Table details should be your first section, that can contain multiple rows.

By this way your height will be automatically managed by `tableview`.

Comment: but for first table view i am having radio button so that whenever it is active then only i need to show remaining views if not it should be hided is it possible with one table view ?@Lion

Comment: you can  manage that by just one flag. Take one flag and initially set it's value as false. Then in number of section method check that if this flag is false then return 1 else your total number of sections. And on change of radio button set that flag true and false and reload table!

Comment: how to set any example i am new to swift 3 ? @Lion

Comment: google it. You will get many tutorials or articles ! It is not possible to explain everything here!

Comment: bro on ur idea i had implemented in single table view but not able to hide can u help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901646/how-to-hide-sections-in-a-table-view-using-a-radio-button  @Lion