# How to hide sections in a table view using a radio button?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here i am having four sections in a table view but in  the first section all the cells are having radio buttons. Whenever it is active, I need to show remaining three sections, if not I need to hide the remaining last three sections can anyone help me how to implement this ?

The image is as shown below[image] ?

```
 @IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
        let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
        if sender.isSelected {

        } else{
            if(chekIndex == nil){
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
                self.ProductTableView.reloadData()
            }
        } 
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
     return 4
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if (section == 0){
            return "PAYMENT INFORMATION"
        }
        else if (section == 1){
            return "ORDER REVIEW"
        }
        else if (section == 2){
            return "PRODUCT"
        }
        else{
            return ""
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (section == 0){
            return paymentmethodsArray.count
        }
        else if (section == 2) {
            return productsDetails.count
        }
        else{
            return 1
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        if (indexPath.section == 0){
            return 44
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            return 410
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 2){
            return 120
        }
        else{
            return 230
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.section == 0){
            let paymentcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "paymentcell",for:indexPath) as! paymentTableViewCell
            myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let arr = self.paymentmethodsArray[indexPath.row]
            paymentcell.paymentNameLabel.text = arr["name"]as? String
            paymentcell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
            if(checkIndex != nil){
                paymentcell.radioButton.isSelected = true
            }else{
                paymentcell.radioButton.isSelected = false
            }
            return paymentcell
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            let shippingAddresscell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingaddresscell",for:indexPath) as! ShippingAddressTableViewCell
            shippingAddresscell.nameLabel.text = name
            shippingAddresscell.addressLabel.text = billingaddress
            shippingAddresscell.mobileNumberLabel.text = String(describing: phoneNumber)
            shippingAddresscell.shippingNameLabel.text = name
            shippingAddresscell.shippingAddressLabel.text = billingaddress
            shippingAddresscell.shippingMobileNumberLabel.text = String(describing: phoneNumber)
            shippingAddresscell.shippingMethodNameLabel.text = shippingMethod
            shippingAddresscell.paymentMethodNameLabel.text = paymentMethod
            return shippingAddresscell
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 2){
            let productNamecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productNamecell",for:indexPath) as! ProductNameTableViewCell
            let arr = productsDetails[indexPath.row]
            let array = arr["product name"] as! String
            productNamecell.productNameLabel.text = array
            productNamecell.priceLabel.text = arr["Price"] as! String
            productNamecell.QuantityLabel.text = String(describing: arr["Quantity"] as! Int)
            productNamecell.subTotalLabel.text = arr["SubTotal"] as! String
            return productNamecell
        }
        else{
            let ordercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ordercell",for:indexPath) as! orderTableViewCell
            ordercell.subTotalLabel.text = subTotal
            ordercell.shippingLabel.text = shippingHandling
            ordercell.grandTotalLabel.text = total
            return ordercell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can multiple radio buttons be selected at the same time?

Comment: no only one will be active at a time

Comment: when it is active then i need to show all sections if not i need to show only first section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one flag (Bool I mean), It's initial value will be `false`. now on radio button's selection set it's value to `true`.

Now, change `numberofSection` method. It will conditionally returns `1` or `4`. I mean if your flag was `true` then return `4` else `1`! that's it!

Comment: bro i am having different cell sizes without giving row height can i change the cell size automatically ?@Lion

Comment: I am not getting what you are asking exactly

Comment: now in the code  height for row at index path i had given different row sizes for different sections without giving this can i change it automatically ?

Comment: that means if second section got increased then how to change row height  automatically

Comment: You should take a look on `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`!

Comment: i tried by using this but it didn't change my table view row height automatically @Lion

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to change the `numberOfSections` method according to the condition. Instead of returning `numberOfSections` as 4 you need to change it according to the radio button selection.
You can keep a boolean variable to check whether the button is selected or not and based on its value change numberOfSections method like

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
let numberOfRows = ifRadioButtonSelected ? 4 : 1
     return numberOfRows
    }
```

Comment: that means i need to implement number of sections in radio button action ?

Comment: how to implement that can u tell me ?

Comment: Just keep a boolean variable to check whether the button is selected or not and based on its value change numberOfSections method

Answer (score 1):

Keep the `Bool` variable to identify the radio button is selected or not based on that return the `count` of `number of section`.

```
 var isRadioButtonSelected = false

 @IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {

  //Your remaining logic here.

  //Based on the selection action you have to update the flag value.
  if sender.isSelected {
     isRadioButtonSelected =  true
  } else {
     isRadioButtonSelected =  false
  }

    // Reload table
    self.ProductTableView.reloadData()
 }

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
    if  isRadioButtonSelected ==  true {
      return 4
    } else {
      return 1
    } 
  }
```