# Can't position UIView to the bottom of TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I tried to position the UIView to the bottom of the tableView but it always position itself to the bottom of the Navigation Bar

1. Promocode View is the UIView
2. Location TableView is the tableView

[image]

After I added the constraints to the bottom of the TableView

[image]

What should I do to position it nicely under the tableView?

Comment: You see that the Autolayout is marked red, this means that you are missing constraints. Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901928/uitextview-not-visible-on-uiscrollview/45910576#45910576 , not the part about the UIScrollView tho, but the second part about how to see missing constraints etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the correct path here. Adding constraints to the promo code view was the right thing to do.

However, once you started adding constraints to a view, IB tries to figure out the frame of the view basing solely on the constraints. If it can't, those red lines appear. You've only added this constraint:

[image]

right? This constraint says that the promo code view will always be 4 pixels under whatever is above it i.e. the table view.

The constraint you added defines the y position of the promo code view. To figure out its frame, you still need three more things:

- x position
- width
- height

For the width and height, you probably want them to be fixed at the current value, so add these two constraints:

[image]

For the x position, I think you intend it to be centered? Then move it to the centre and add this constraint:

[image]

You also need to add constraints for the table view as well. I suggest a top, leading, trailing and height constraint.

After you're done, it should look like this:

[image]