# App resizes on deployment to iphone 6s - xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a simple single screen app with two buttons that looks great on the story board on xcode. As soon as I run the app on my iphone 6s, it resizes the screen and the buttons at the bottom disappear. It looks like the resolution has changed and the app is not meant for an iphone 6s screen.

I have already tried the following without any success:

1) Enabled "Use Auto Layout" for my View controller in the File Inspector menu(under utilities)

2) Set the deployment target to "10.3", Devices to "iPhone" and checked "portrait, landscape left and landscape right" for Device orientation under the General Settings.

Is there any other setting that I might have missed to check that is causing this scaling? I am using xcode 8.3

Edit: I recieved some great feedback in the comments section, and learnt about adding constraints. I am here adding screenshots of what my app looks like before and after adding constraints:

Here is my xcode storyboard (what I am looking to get on my iPhone 6s)

[image]

And here is a screenshot of what I have on my phone (prior to constraining)

[image]

I have tried constraining the view like so with no luck (same output on the phone):

[image]

Is there a specific set of constraints that will do the job here?

Comment: This sounds like AutoLayout constraints issue. You need to check your constraints , if you can't find the issue, provide screenshots / details about what you have set to your constraints etc to be able to locate your issue. Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901928/uitextview-not-visible-on-uiscrollview/45910576#45910576 and see the screenshots about the AutoLayout part might help you in the right direction. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: Every object set in the Story Board requires constraints be set (through Autolayout) that specifies the position of the object (x,y), and the size.  Sounds like you haven't done that.

Comment: Thank you @MartinMuldoon for your suggestions, I have made the edits in the questions and added the screenshots. Also tried a few combinations with the constraints without much luck. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Sneak for you advice, I have added screenshots to the post here and am experimenting with constraints now. Any advice on what constraints might need to be worked on here, in my case would be very useful. Thanks

Comment: @Veer NP, I strongly suggest you take your time to read tutorials and keep experimenting until you learn it. There are many, many tutorials both on Google and YouTube. (example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwkpyzn7EOM) Giving you a pointer to set a simple constraint here wont do you any good or teach you anything. It will be a little hard to grasp the first minutes/hour in, but take your time to study and experiment,you will eventually grasp everything and it will become easy

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots show that you have not set your constraints. The last screenshot shows that you have set some constraints on the root view. Like mentioned by Martin you need to have constraints for each object.

To place the button correctly at the bottom of the view, you need to draw from your button to your view (holding the ctrl-key) and then select the bottom, leading and trailing constraints.

I suggest to make a beginner tutorial in Autolayout with InterfaceBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your great responses. Turns out the solution was a little different than just experimenting with constraints. It took me about 3 hours to figure this out, and I wanted to share the simple solution here in case someone else goes through the same thing in the future.

The problem was in the General section of the settings. Your Launch Screen File must reflect the MainStoryboard like so:

[image]

My Launch Screen File option was previously set to nothing which caused the problem. As soon as I changed it to the MainStoryboard, things look just fine.
Hope this helps someone!