# How to work with AutoLayout and UIScrollView, can't pull to refresh

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I've worked with Xcode for a while and learnt more or less how AutoLayout works. For this project I had to add a UIScrollView to implement pull to refresh and put all my outlets inside that UIScrollView.

I'd like, for all sizes, that my app was the same but the content resized. The problem appears when I added the UIScrollView. I added all the constraints and in Xcode it looked great but when testing it in the Simulator the ScrollView is locked, I can't move the view to do pull to refresh.

My app has this elements.

[image: this]

And looks like [image: this].

Is there a method on how to work with AutoLayout and UIScrollViews?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901928/uitextview-not-visible-on-uiscrollview/45910576#45910576 and You need to set contentSize and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces / https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical for it to not be "locked" and always bounce. You can do this in storyboard or in code. Just select the UIScrollView in storyboard and select it to bounce on right side, check the boxes. Make sure you have no wierd or broken autolayout constraints first, as from my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView not visible on UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901928/uitextview-not-visible-on-uiscrollview)